python equivalent of ruby's Hash#dig
I work a lot with nested formats like JSON and YAML, that have dicts and lists so wrote this utility.
from typing import Any, Hashable, Iterable, Protocol, TypeVar, runtime_checkable

T = TypeVar("T")
K = TypeVar("K", bound=Hashable)


@runtime_checkable
class SupportsGetItem(Protocol[K, T]):
    def __getitem__(self, __key: K) -> T:
        ...


SupportsNestedAccess = SupportsGetItem[Hashable, Any]


def dig(
    container: SupportsNestedAccess,
    keys: Iterable[Hashable],
    default: Any = None,
    suppress_exceptions: bool = True,
) -> Any:
    """
    Retrieve a nested value from a container.

    :param container: A data structure supporting key/item access, e.g., list, dict, tuple.
    :param keys: A sequence of keys to access the nested value. E.g. [0, 'foo', 'bar'].
    :param default: Value to return if the key is not found (used when suppress_exceptions is True).
    :param suppress_exceptions: If True, return default when key is not found; if False, raise an exception.
    :return: The nested value, or default if the key is not found and suppress_exceptions is True.

    >>> dig({1: {2: 3}}, [1, 2])
    3
    >>> dig({1: {2: 3}}, [1])
    {2: 3}
    >>> dig({1: {2: 3}}, [1, 3]) is None
    True
    >>> dig({1: {2: 3}}, [1, 3], default='Not Found')
    'Not Found'
    >>> dig({1: {2: 3}}, [4]) is None
    True
    >>> dig({1: {2: 3}}, [4], suppress_exceptions=False)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    KeyError: 4
    >>> dig([1, 2, 3], [5], suppress_exceptions=False)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    IndexError: list index out of range
    """
    current = container
    for key in keys:
        try:
            current = current[key]
        except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError) as e:
            if suppress_exceptions:
                return default
            else:
                raise e

    return current


This is interesting enough, but it loses information about the container. If it's a mapping, you would want to use get. Is there any specific reason that this needs to be only one method?

@Reinderien, yes, that's the down side of being container agnostic

As a side-note, KeyError and IndexError share a common parent class, LookupError, so you can reduce the number of exceptions you list to (LookupError, TypeError).

@ShadowRanger Right, thx. I'm just wondering whether it'd be better to give a more specific error message when an exception arises

Consider accessing deeply nested records using
glom.
dunder
class SupportsGetItem( ... ):
    def __getitem__(self, __key: ...

It's unclear why we're asking for
name mangling
here. If there's some design consideration which
motivates it, that should be explicitly spelled out here.
The OP mentioned no relevant use of inheritance taking advantage of that "feature".
A straightforward reading of
the docs
suggests that simply key would be the conventional parameter name
to put in the signature.
design of Public API
The API is very nice and is reasonably simple,
clearly designed for convenience of the caller.
    default: Any = None,
    suppress_exceptions: bool = True,

The boolean mode is sensible enough,
but it slightly complicates exposition in the docstring.
Consider assigning signal_exceptions = object(),
and then caller can specify that sentinel with
dig({1: {2: 3}}, [4], signal_exceptions).
This would let us dispense with that fourth mode parameter.
Maybe such an approach would be simpler for caller?
raise
        except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError) as e:
                ...
                raise e

nit: I think raise would suffice there, no need to bind e.
Alternatively, you might wish to define a brand new
NestedAccessError or DigError which wraps e,
and reveals the current value of key as part
of a helpful diagnostic.
doctest
Thank you for providing that.
The API, its implementation, and the documentation all look great, well done.

It's unclear why we're asking for name mangling here, most likely the OP copied that style from a source that used pre-PEP-570 spelling of positional only arguments. Prior to PEP 570, prefixing parameters with a double-underscore was the standard way to denote positional only arguments. This is still supported by type checkers to this day (as a requirement of the typing spec). That said, it doesn't look like the OP is worried about compatibility with Python<3.8, since they use other 3.8+ features

@Brian61354270, thank you, that's very helpful. Here's the PEP-570 reference.

Thanks a lot! I actually saw glom when doing the research, but was put off by the a.b.c syntax. Also, using a library for such a simple function (typing aside) seemed an overkill

To make it clear, parameter names do not undergo name mangling - using __getitem__(__key=...) will work.

It's actually a bad idea to do raise e, as that raises it as if it were a brand-new raised exception (discarding the traceback from where it was originally raised, thought with exception-chaining, you'll see that if you look far enough back). Bare raise re-raises the active exception as if it was never caught, preserving the original traceback, which is definitely what you want here.
